# What is the default state in MotionLayout?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I couldn't find any documentation regarding default state of `MotionScene` in `MotionLayout`.

I have simple `MotionScene` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <Transition
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/customStart"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/customEnd"
        app:duration="250" />


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/customStart">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/someId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/customEnd">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/someId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    </ConstraintSet>


</MotionScene>
```

So how does `MotionLayout` set default state when view is firstly created? And how can I manually set, say `customEnd`, as default state?

Comment: app:constraintSetStart is used to determine the default state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MotionScene now has `StateSet` element which has an attribute for the default state.

```
<StateSet app:defaultState="@id/start"/>
```

Comment: This will not work if you already have `constraintSetStart` inside `MotionScene`

Answer (score 1):

First `constraintSetStart` inside `MotionScene` defines the default state of `MotionLayout`.

If you want to change it, you can do it by calling

```
motionLayout.setState(R.id.constraintSetId, motionLayout.width, motionLayout.height)
```

inside your `Fragment` or `Activity`.